# How to flip texture vertically in WebGPU?

Tags: webgpu

After reading through the specs and googling a lot, I still can't find a way to flip a texture vertically in WebGPU.

I am looking for something along the lines of `gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true)` in WebGL.

Is it even possible? I guess it should happen somewhere in `device.createTexture()` or `device.queue.copyExternalImageToTexture()` calls, but can't find anything.

For the time being, I invert my UVs in the fragment shader, but am looking for a less hacky solution.

Comment: I think this is a sign of a deeper problem. Flipping the texture before upload is as much of a hack as inverting UVs in the fragment shader. I assume you are porting WebGL code to WebGPU. You should adjust your coordinate systems accordingly. (0,0) UV tex coord corresponded to bottom-left pixel in WebGL, but it corresponds to the top-left pixel in WebGPU.

Comment: fair enough, this makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `flipY: true` of `device.queue.copyExternalImageToTexture`'s first parameter.

```js
device.queue.copyExternalImageToTexture({ source: imageBitmap, flipY: true }, { texture: texture }, [imageBitmap.width, imageBitmap.height]);
```